# CGI script does not run

Tags: php, cgi

i have a CGI script . When I try to run it , Browser tries to download it. Instead of running.

I have the cgi web hosting and I've put scripts in CGI directory.

Comment: Does it have correct permissions, does it have a shebang line, does it have any executable code?

Comment: If its PHP, then it will be a problem with the permission.

Comment: file permission is 755 and script is standard  http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the permission setting of the cgi script is 755 and the script has no errors then the following should solve it:

**If you host with a shared host provider:**

If you are on shared hosting then contact your web host and ask them if Perl is enabled with your web hosting. If it is not enabled then ask them to turn on Perl support for your web hosting or ask them what you should do to enable Perl for your web hosting.

It may also be a hosting related problem. If this is the case then only they will be able to fix it for you. As a shared hosting customer you can ask them to fix it for you as you are not able to run Perl scripts.

**If this is your own server:**

It most likely means that Perl is not properly configured.

If your web server is Apache then you can find instructions for that here:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-enable-cgi-on-your-apache-server/

If the instructions at the above link is not helpful then a search for 'configure cgi-bin for YOUR_FLAVOUR_OF_LINUX' - you should get a wealth of information to help you properly configure the cgi-bin directory on your flavor of Linux.

If your server is Windows based then the following should be helpful:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44536 - You will want configuration information for your web server and Perl. There should be a wealth of information available when you search for: 'configure cgi-bin for windows YOUR_WEB_SERVER_NAME'

YOUR_WEB_SERVER_NAME could be IIS (IIS is a Windows Web Server) for example.